# Change a single Wordpress website setup as a multi site with no subdomains to non multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Worpress multi-site for our company because we originally planned on doing subdomains for different markets i.e eu.vapetasia.com for Europe, however, we never did. The site is currently multisite with one website, vapetasia.com. Because it's multi-site, Siteground hosting staging sites do not work and I need to test upgrading plugins before doing it on the live site. Since I'm not moving a subdomain I can't use a migration plugin. I tried just commenting out the multi-site additions to wp-config.php but that broke the site. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**First way : without no new installation**

1. Delete or Migrate all of the Sites in the Network
2. Uninstall and Delete Themes and Plugins Not Used by the Base Site
3. Remove Users Without Access to the Base Site
4. Deactivate WordPress Multisite on Your WordPress Installation
5. Drop the Database Tables Added by Multisite

open the `wp-config.php` file and find these lines:

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
$base = '/.../';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '....' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/..../' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Delete all of those lines.

Find the line that reads:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

Edit it so it reads:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false);
```

Now save your `wp-config.php` file.
You also need might need to edit your `.htaccess` file to revert it to the code for a single site.

---

**Second : Fresh installation:**

1. Create plugins & theme zip files on a subsite (WordPress Multisite)
2. Install a new Single WordPress site
3. Upload subsite plugins.zip & themes.zip files to a single site
4. Export your all subsite content & data
5. Import data to a fresh WordPress site